# Selenium-java 4.11.0 Creating ChromeDriver failed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, seleniummanager

Upgraded selenium-java to `4.11.0` getting below error on Jenkin  machines.

```
Creating ChromeDriver failedchromedriver located at C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64\116.0.5845.96\chromedriver.exe, but invalid

Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.17'
```

upgraded selenium-java to `4.11.0` and trying to run on Jenkins windows machines.

Only `chomredriver\win32` folder was present. Deleted the `.cache` folder and re ran the job now I do not see folder getting created but still getting same error.